# How to detect if PHP JIT is enabled

Tags: php, jit, php-8

What is the simplest way to detect if PHP is compiled with JIT and JIT is enabled from the running script?

Comment: so you want a way to check in your script if it's been compiled or interpreted?

Comment: Ideally both, but at least if interpreted.

Comment: Also, phpinfo() will show it under the "Zend OPcache" section that simply says "JIT       On|Disabled".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can query the opcache settings directly by calling [`opcache_get_status()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-status.php):

```
opcache_get_status()["jit"]["enabled"];
```

or perform a lookup in the `php.ini`:

```
ini_get("opcache.jit")
```

which is an integer (returned as string) where the last digit states the status of the JIT:

```
0 - don't JIT
1 - minimal JIT (call standard VM handlers)
2 - selective VM handler inlining
3 - optimized JIT based on static type inference of individual function
4 - optimized JIT based on static type inference and call tree
5 - optimized JIT based on static type inference and inner procedure analyses
```

Source: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/jit#phpini_defaults

Comment: It seems it does not work - `var_dump(ini_get("opcache.jit"));` returns `string(4) "1205"` for with JIT and without JIT, tested using https://3v4l.org/Q366F

Comment: @mvorisek I've updated my answer. I guess the opcache_get_status() function is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, the following works: `opcache_get_status()["jit"]['enabled'] ?? false`

Comment: Wrap the answer in a `var_dump()` to get it to print out the boolean value. e.g. `var_dump(opcache_get_status()["jit"]["enabled"]);`.... returns e.g. `bool(false)` or `bool(true)`.

Comment: `opcache_get_status` is working, but it's terribly slow, ~40ms, if someone have a fastest way...

Comment: @luigifab I cannot reproduce it, the method executes on my server in around 6 to 8 ms. I wouldn't even call 40 ms that long, if this time is an issue to you, you maybe shouldn't query it that often, sounds more like an issue with the algorithm you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 4):

```
php -i | grep "opcache"

checking:
opcache.enable => On => On
opcache.enable_cli => On => On
opcache.jit => tracing => tracing
```

Comment: Please update your answer with some details about your code and how does it answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

`opcache_get_status()` will not work when JIT is disabled and will throw Fatal error.

```
echo (function_exists('opcache_get_status') 
      && opcache_get_status()['jit']['enabled']) ? 'JIT enabled' : 'JIT disabled';
```

We must have following settings for JIT in `php.ini` file.

```
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1 //optional, for CLI interpreter
opcache.jit_buffer_size=32M //default is 0, with value 0 JIT doesn't work
opcache.jit=1235 //optional, default is "tracing" which is equal to 1254
```