# How to understand that PHP.8 JIT is included in the docker image?

Tags: php, docker, jit, php-8

I'm a bit confused now, because after adding the JIT setting to the PHP config, when I disable the `opcache_get_status()['jit']` function, I get the following output:
[image]

But after checking `ini_get("opcache.jit")` I have the following result:

[image]

Which in turn, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62654537/11419254), means that JIT is active:

> which is an integer (returned as string) where the last digit states the status of the JIT:
> ...
> 5 - optimized JIT based on static type inference and inner procedure analyses

I still think that my JIT is not active, although maybe there is an expert who will explain that this is not the case)) since the function itself is called, maybe **XDebug** is involved here because it is active for me, but these are more guesswork.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine

ENV XDEBUG_VERSION 3.1.5

RUN apk add --update --no-cache icu-dev icu-libs icu-data-full git bash autoconf g++ make zlib-dev libzip-dev libpng-dev libwebp-dev freetype-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    && git clone --branch $XDEBUG_VERSION --depth 1 https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git /usr/src/php/ext/xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-configure xdebug --enable-xdebug-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl pdo_mysql gd zip xdebug \
    && apk del git

RUN mv $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini

# fix work iconv library with alphine
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ --allow-untrusted gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

COPY ./common/php/conf.d /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY ./development/php/conf.d /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
COPY ./development/php-fpm/conf.d /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

COPY ./development/php-fpm/entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint

WORKDIR /app
```

opcache.ini

```ini
zend_extension=opcache.so
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.jit_buffer_size=128M
opcache.jit=1255
```